# How to connect a DAO database with an ODBC in vb6

Tags: vb6, odbc, isam

I need make a connection using DAO 3.6 in Visual basic clasic

I have this:

```
Dim worksp As Workspace
Dim conexString As String
Set worksp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Let conexString = "OBDC;DSN=daclidb;UID=;PWD="
Set Base = worksp.OpenDatabase("", False, False, conexString)
```

But I have an error in the last line:

> "Can't Find Installable ISAM" Error

Comment: What kind of database does daclidb point to? Can you configure in by going to Control Panel - ODBC?

Comment: Yes is a odbc control panel database and is make it in access

Comment: But are you able to configure the DSN, and test the connection in the control panel? If not, depending on the OS it's possible you do not have JET installed. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114

Comment: I am able to do that using ADODB but not Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

Comment: Do you get the error on the same machine VB6 is installed, or on a different machine?

Comment: Try this: Set Base = worksp.OpenDatabase("daclidb", False, False, conexString) Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835343%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Did you try to install "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 or "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 ?

Comment: Yes but no luck with nothing, so I changed all my code for Adodb :(